# Domain with www on different IP than non-www

Tags: http, redirect, dns, http-redirect

I'm doing my best to learn and understand how DNS works. On my journey, I found something interesting. I've seen several cases, including [chanel.com](http://chanel.com) and [prada.com](http://prada.com), where the website redirects from domain.com to www.domain.com. That's understandable and I've explored this debatable subject in the past. What's new though is that in these cases, the www version is on another IP. So if we open the [chanel.com](http://chanel.com), it makes a 301 redirection to [www.chanel.com](http://www.chanel.com), which happens to have different IP. What are the potential benefits and reasons of this idea?

Comment: `www` is no different than any other subdomain, and is free to have its own IP. [**This ServerFault question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/675089/subdomain-with-different-ip-on-same-server) asks the same thing, and it seems that the only real advantage is to have different services available.

Comment: But I don't think that answer covers the www and non-www issue. I understand separating services, but in that case it's just redirection. I don't think chanel.com will ever serve any other content that www.chanel.com, in reality one of them will always just be redirection.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of companies have seperate servers or applications to handle redirects, so the real website is only listening to www.example.com and the domain example.com is pointing to the redirect server who is giving the redirect.

This is useful for managing all your redirects in one place, for example you got the domain www.example2.com that should redirect to www.example.com you can handle that easily on the same server. and even redirect to a specific page like www.example.com/example2

Cheers!

Comment: But that can be done just that easily on one machine, am I wrong?